# Re-sizing site's Body and iframe when the page link is clicked

Tags: javascript

I have an iframe that loads a page inside it.. when a link is clicked on the page in the iframe, resize the body of the parent aka the document that has the iframe's body..

```
 Body         <------------------------
    Iframe                            |
        Page                          |
         Link... Upon Click, resize body --
```

How do I do the above? I tried Parent.document.body.style.width = "200px". and it didn't work. Not sure what to do. Please Help!

```
function Parentresize(id)
{
var newheight = 2000;
var newwidth = 2000;
parent.document.getElementById(id).height= (newheight) + "px";
parent.document.getElementById(id).width= (newwidth) + "px";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. This code will exactly do that. It is a bit lengthy because of extra code for cross browser compatibility:

```
function WindowSize()
{
    WinWidth = 0, WinHeight = 0;    //Initialize variables with a value of 0;
    if(typeof(parent.window.innerWidth) == 'number')    //Well I need the parent width of the iFrame aka browser width. Width is a number, not undefined..
    {
            //FireFox/Opera..
        WinWidth = parent.window.innerWidth;
        WinHeight = parent.window.innerHeight;
    }
    else if(parent.document.documentElement && (parent.document.documentElement.clientWidth || parent.document.documentElement.clientHeight))
    {
        //IE 6+
        WinWidth = parent.document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        WinHeight = parent.document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    }
    return WinWidth;
}

function BodyResize(ID)
{
    var IDTag = parent.document.getElementById(ID);

    if(IDTag.clientWidth == '1024')
        IDTag.style.width = (WindowSize() + 'px');
    else
        IDTag.style.width = '1024px';
}
```

just call this function `BodyResize(ID)` 
as
 
`<body id="mainbody" onClick="BodyResize('mainbody')">`
  or
 `<iframe  id="interframe" onClick="BodyResize('interframe')">`

Answer (score 1):

I think you have missed the `style.height` and `style.width`

This is the code I used in `iframe`

```
<script language="javascript">
    function Parentresize(id)
    {
        alert("U r there");
        var newheight = 200;
        var newwidth = 200;
        parent.document.getElementById(id).style.height = newheight + "px";
        parent.document.getElementById(id).style.width = newwidth + "px";
    }
</script>


<a href="javascript:Parentresize('sam');" >Call Me </a>
```

Comment: @sothunders I have script for opposite scenario also.